# Sonar 5.6 and Cobertura?

Tags: sonarqube, cobertura

Does Sonar 5.6 support Cobertura? We had the Sonar Cobertura plugin install with v5.5, and coverage worked great. When we upgraded to 5.6 we started getting the following:

```
mvn site sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.dev.abc.com
```

produced

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project flex-metadatamerge: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaResourceLocator.findResourceByClassName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Resource;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin/2.7.1/sonar-maven-plugin-2.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.5/plexus-utils-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/sonar-runner/sonar-runner-api/2.5-RC1/sonar-runner-api-2.5-RC1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

I removed the Cobertura plugin from Sonar, and that fixed the build issue but now I have no coverage. The weird thing is is that the plugin is no longer listed in the "updatecenter/available" admin page in Sonar!

Any ideas where its gone or what we're doing wrong?

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an API incompatibility between the current version of the Cobertura plugin, 1.6.x, and version 4.0 of the Java plugin.

Cobertura 1.7 will be compatible and should be [available soon](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!searchin/sonarqube/cobertura%7Csort:date/sonarqube/AGGQJLa1KZA/HoOMq9-yBAAJ).

**Edit**

Cobertura 1.7 was released on 22 July 2016